# When trying to retrieves an organizational unit with a + inside the value I'm getting 404

Tags: google-api, google-directory-api

Getting 404 on request like:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/orgunits/DEVICE/DEVICE-Meet-HW-Timezones/DEVICE-Meet-HW-GMT+06-TimeZone
```

The same requests with the org unit id return the expected result.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/my_customer/orgunits/id:{org unit id}
```

I don't see any problem with other org units without the'+', is there some sort of encoding that I need to use? I tried URL encoding but it doesn't work.

Comment: How are you making these requests please include your code.

Comment: There is no code just HTTP request from postman like I posted with the bearer token.